# cordova installation failure using npm

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, npm

I am tried to install cordova in windows machine . But it shows some error related with version . Shows "npm ERR! Error: No compatible version found: update-notifier@'^0.5.0'"

[image]

After updating node js version issue goes .Other installation issue is below

[image]

Thanks

Comment: try update your node and npm

Comment: updated node js , so version related error goes .But issue with some other  .Included screen shots with updated question

Comment: Try to run CMD as a Administrator. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc947813(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Thank u @Tomislav  :) , successfully done the installation  , run the command as administrator

Comment: I'm glad I could help. :) I'll put my comment above as answer below so that others can find it easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Start a Command Prompt as an Administrator](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc947813(v=ws.10).aspx).

[image]

1. Click **Start**.
2. In the **Start Search** box, type **cmd**.
3. Right-click **Command prompt**, and then click **Run as administrator**.